# Filtering in template via derived method on DataObject

Tags: php, templates, filter, silverstripe

I have two data objects `parent` and `child` with `parent` having many `child`ren. `Child` has a few `boolean`s that describe it's state and should only be displayed on this particular page if in a certain state.

In my template I have:

```
<% with $Parent %>
<% if $Child %><h1>Children</h1>
    <% loop $Child %>
        <p>$Child.Title</p>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
<% end_with %>
```

However this will obviously show all the `Child`ren, I can put a filter on it:

```
<% $Child.Filter('Show', '1') %>
```

However I can't do multiple items for the filter (at least that I can figure out), so I thought I'd make a function on the `DataObject` that would be the derived boolean to show it, however this isn't something I can filter on.

Whats the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say these are our `Child` and `Parent` classes:

**Child**

```
class Child extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(1024)',
        'Awesome' => 'Boolean',
        'Fun' => 'Boolean'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Parent' => 'Parent'
    );
}
```

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(1024)'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Children' => 'Child'
    );
}
```

We can add functions to the `Parent` class to return various filtered `Children` lists:

```
class Parent extends DataObject {
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Children' => 'Child'
    );

    public function getAwesomeChildren() {
        return $this->Children()->filter('Awesome', true);
    }

    public function getAwesomeFunChildren() {
        return $this->Children()->filter(array(
            'Awesome' => true,
            'Fun' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

In our template we can call:

```
<% if $AwesomeChildren %>
    <h1>Children</h1>
    <% loop $AwesomeChildren %>
        <p>$Title</p>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```